# search for and return rows matching search in a group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a fairly complex query with tons of joins all over the place. The query itself works perfectly, with the appropriate grouping by id to only show the distinct values, and I'm using `GROUP BY` to account for a `COUNT()` field, and I have 3 fields that contain serial numbers.

The problem is, let's assume there are 3 rows that share the same id. each of those three rows have different serial numbers in the three serial number columns, similar to below:

```
Row     ID      SN1     SN2     SN3
1       1       abc123  (null)  (null)
2       1       (null)  def456  (null)
3       1       (null)  (null)  xyz789
```

When grouping-by ID, the first row will appear in the recordset, which is fine, but it also means that if I do a `LIKE '%def%'`, the row will simply not appear at all.

Is MySQL performing the WHERE part first or the GROUP BY first? it appears that it's grouping first, which is why only a `LIKE '%abc%'` works. Is there any way to swap that order around?

The real query is 60 lines so I don't really want to paste it, but will if it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` is applied before `GROUP BY`.

If you want to filter first, then group, use a `WHERE` condition.
If you want to `GROUP BY` first, then filter, use the `HAVING` clause.

If you want all your serial numbers in the result, you can use SELECT `GROUP_CONCAT(SN1) AS all_sn1` in the aggregation phase. More about [GROUP_CONCA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in the manual.

If you want all your serial numbers of all three columns in one column, concatenate them together. One possible way:

```
SELECT COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(SN1) || ' ', '')
    || COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(SN1) || ' ', '')
    || COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(SN1), '')
```

Could have an trailing sapce. [Trim](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) it if you care.

Comment: Thank you, that put me on the correct path. Somehow I overlooked that function (as I have used it before) ... I was hoping for exact-match searching, but it'd rather it be working :) +1